# Load Issue on MySql Server

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I'm facing an load issue on MySql Server database.
In our application we have an requirement of inserting ,fetching and updating data for each call/click.

We are doing the load testing on this application, we wrote an program to call this application do it functionality. we running this test program for more than 400 times (I mean 400 instances) in MySql more than 100 connections are created and test program was throwing "The underlying provider failed on Open. -Too many connections"

I have set the max_connection variable to 400 and did the same testing but this time it was throwing  "Thread stack overrun:  137376 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and 128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a bigger stack."

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Do you make use of connection pooling?

Comment: This application is build in ASP.net MVC3 and Entity Framework, can you please help me how can I implement connection pooling.

Comment: Ok np, what provider to you use to connect? ODBC?

Comment: This is a really good guide: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q169470

Comment: Hi Kay Nelson,
I have implemented the connection pooling but I'm facing an issue when 400 users access application , I have observed in IIS workprocess there are more than 850 requests pending how can I fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by doing small modification in web.config and mysql variable setting

1) `<httpRuntime executionTimeout = "number(in seconds)" />`
this is used, to remove the request when it take's more time in process the request
2) By increasing the max_connections variable size in mysql
3) there was issue in the load testing application itself , it was sending the request without any time gap, so set the time gap between each request.

Now I can run up to 600 users instance at a same time , but load will be on CUP and MySql.

Thank you Kay Nelson for your quick reply.

Regards,
Sampath Kumar J